# How do I add a username and password to a return in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, terminal, terminal-emulator

I am working on a fake terminal so I can prepare for making a terminal for our robotics team. I want to know how to add a username [SSID] and a password [PSWD] for admins to use certain commands that people who do not know the password can't use. How would I do this?

Here is My code

```js
    // setup vars
    var currentLine = "";
    var typeSpeed = 70;
    var pauseLength = 1000;
    
    // get ref to DOM Elements
    var cursor = $("#cursor");
    var animate = $(".animate");
    var input = $("#inputcmd");
    var output = $("#output");
    
    // set up Event Listeners
    input.keypress(keypressInput);
    $("#terminal-window").click(openKeyboard);
    
    // hide text so we can animate it
    animate.each(function(index) {
      $(this).addClass("hide");
    });
    
    // make first call to printCharaters() for animation
    var temp = setTimeout(printCharaters, typeSpeed);
    
    // this function animates printing of text inside DOMS with the .animate class.
    function printCharaters() {
      // check if current line array is empty
      if (currentLine.length == 0) {
        // stop cursor from blinking
        cursor.removeClass("blink");
    
        // get first line of text and add it to an array
        currentLine = animate.first().text().split("");
        currentLine = currentLine.reverse();
    
        // remove text from dom and unhide element
        animate.first().html("");
        animate.first().removeClass("hide");
        cursor.appendTo(animate.first());
      }
    
      // animate typing
      animate.first().append(currentLine.pop()).append(cursor);
    
      // check if we just popped the last element of the array off
      if (currentLine.length == 0) {
        // remove animated DOM Element from animation
        animate.first().removeClass("animate");
        // get new list of DOM Elements to animate
        animate = $(".animate");
        // make cursor blink at the end-of-line.
        cursor.addClass("blink");
    
        // Animate next DOM Element if any remain
        if (animate.length > 0) {
          setTimeout(printCharaters, pauseLength);
        } else {
          // all text in the DOM Elements have been animated
          input.after(cursor);
          input.focus();
        }
      } else {
        // Animate next character in DOM Element
        setTimeout(printCharaters, typeSpeed);
      }
    }
    
    function keypressInput(e) {
      // received enter key, send cmd and clear input
      if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var command = input.text();
        output.html(proccessCMD(command));
        input.html("");
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
    
    function proccessCMD(cmd) {
      cmd = cmd.trim().toLowerCase();
      //there is only one command here. But you get the idea. Plug in your API call here.
      //commands for basic users
      if (cmd == "--help") {
        return "try these command types: ls, cd ip, vpn, ping, date, time, cal, data, su, termlink_shutdown, termlink_boot, server, wi-fi, file, chat, reload, clear";
      }
      if (cmd == "ls /") {
        return "bin | src | lib | lib64 | dev | sbin"
      }
      if (cmd == "ls /bin") {
        return "license.txt | runtime | trash | archived"
      }
      if (cmd == "ls /bin /license") {
        return "This terminal may be shutdown at an unexpected time. We are not liable for amy damages. If you violate this terminal we can take you to a court of our choice. If you have any questions email us at ******.********@gmail.com. Thank you for using this terminal Terminal owned and operated by Nathan Schmitt"
      }
      if (cmd =="ls /bin /runtime") {
        return "runtime exception error! To debug type debug.exe"
      }
      if (cmd == "debug.exe") {
        return 'debuger loading....................................Complete --> Posabilities for an unexpected error: Failed to compile bootstrap files, your terminal sesion ended, your wi-fi has been disconnected, you have entered an incorrect or old command. "The computer is usualy not the problem, but is more likely you or your internet of things" --Bob Peeters. Some commands start or end with slashes. WHITE SPACE DOES COUNT AS AN IMPUT -All errors have been reported'
      }
      if (cmd == "ls /bin /trash") {
        return 'you must enter your admin password to view trash type "su" to enter admin terminal'
      }
      if (cmd == "ssid/pswd:") {
        return "you must be logged in as an admin to use this command!"
      }
      if (cmd == "shutdown") {
        return "you must be logged in as an admin to use this command!"
      }
      if (cmd == "ls /lib") {
        return "Librarry: you must be logged in as an admin to use this command! Use The 'file' or 'lib64' to acsess the non-admin librarry"
      }
      if (cmd == "ls /lib64") {
        return "your lib64: Readme.txt Lisence.txt Runtime.exe ls / cd home cd /create.  your shared lib64:[you have not shared any of your personal files to the public, use Termlink Pro to acsess the share option]  Public lib64: [Kittens.txt] [fun.txt] [why.txt] [termlink.txt] [termlinkPro.txt] Privatelib: you must be logged in as an admin to use this command! **use the file command to acsess lib64 files**"
      }
      if (cmd == "ls /sbin") {
        return "you must be logged in as an admin to use the sbin command"
      }
      if (cmd == "ls /dev") {
        return "terminal development by Nathan Schmitt the src is codepen.io. The terminal is not completed and is still in indev stages, shutdowns are to be expeted in the next month. Thank you for choosing FBI termlink"
      }
      if (cmd == "ls /bin /archived") {
        return "you must be logged in as an admin to use the sbin command"
      }
      if (cmd =="cd /") {
        return "cd /home cd /su cd /server"
      }
      if (cmd == "cd /home") {
        return "destanation reached [directory:'home']"
      }
      if (cmd == "cd /su") {
        return "you must be logged in as an admin to use this command"
      }
      if (cmd == "cd /server") {
        return "you are on server 1. Use termlink pro to get onto any server port! our terminal has 84 ports to choose from. Use 'cd /port' to chose your port. To see full server information you must be logged in as and admin"
      }
      if (cmd == "cd /port") {
        return "make a termlink pro acount today!"
      }
      if (cmd == "clear") {
        return " "
      }
      if (cmd == "reload") {
        return "reload succsessfull"
      }
      if (cmd == "ip") {
        return "ip adress fetching is blocked by your system adminastrator"
      }
      if (cmd == "vpn") {
        return "it seems you do not have a valid vpn"
      }
      if (cmd == "ping") {
        return "[100 packets sent] [87 packets pinged [13 packet loss]"
      }
      if (cmd == "Data") {
        return "server data could not be found on this server [server 1]"
      }
      if (cmd == "termlink_boot") {
      return "boot-up completed in 0.0243785 seconds"
    }
    if (cmd == "termlink_shutdown") {
      return "you are not allowed to do what you just did"
    }
    if (cmd == "wi-fi") {
      return "your router does not allow fetching of this data"
    }
    if (cmd == "file") {
      return "file /readme.txt file/ runtime.exe file/ lisence.txt file /kittens.txt file /myfiles"
    }
```

```css
body,
#inputcmd {
 background-color: #333;
 color: #00ff00;
 font-family: "andale mono", /* MS WebFont */
 "monotype.com", /* MS WebFont, former name */
 monaco, /* MacOS */
 /* Fallback options */
 "courier new", /* Windows, MacOS */
 courier, /* Unix+X, MacOS */
 monospace;
}

#terminal-window {
 padding: 10px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background-color: #111;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#terminal-window:before {
 content: '';
 z-index: 4010;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 background: linear-gradient(#444 50%, #111 50%);
 background-size: 100% 4px;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 opacity: .14;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 animation: pulse 5s linear infinite;
}

#cursor {
 color: #00ffff;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-left: .5em solid;
}

.blink {
 animation: typing 6s steps(13, end) infinite, blinking 1s step-end infinite;
}

.scanlines {
 z-index: 4100;
}

.hide {
 display: none;
}

.scanlines:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 12px;
 background: #fff;
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 250, 250, 1) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.98) 51%, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
 /* W3C */
 opacity: .1;
 animation: vline 6.25s linear infinite;
}

#inputcmd {
 background-color: #111;
 border: 1px;
 font-size: 1em;
 /*hide default cursor*/
 color: transparent;
 text-shadow: 0 0 0 #00ffff;
}

#inputcmd:focus {
 outline: none;
}

@keyframes pulse {
 0% {
  transform: scale(1.001);
  opacity: .14;
 }
 8% {
  transform: scale(1.000);
  opacity: .13;
 }
 15% {
  transform: scale(1.004);
  opacity: .14;
 }
 30% {
  transform: scale(1.002);
  opacity: .11;
 }
 100% {
  transform: scale(1.000);
  opacity: .14;
 }
}

@keyframes vline {
 0% {
  top: 0px;
 }
 100% {
  top: 100%;
 }
}

@keyframes blinking {
 from,
 to {
  border-color: transparent;
 }
 50% {
  border-color: cyan;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="terminal-window">
    <span id="cursor"></span>
    <p>
        <span class="animate">FBI (TM) TERMLINK PROTOCOL INSTANTIATING</span>
    </p>
    <p>
        <span class="animate">PASSWORD REQUIRED</span>
    </p>
    <span class="animate">[Enter Password]>>></span>
    <span class="animate">******************************--Geust Password saved</span>
    <p>
    </p>
    <span class="animate">...</span><span class="animate">Acsess Granted!</span>
    <p>
    </p>
    <span class="animate"> To login as admin type "su"</span>
    <p>
    </p>
    <span class="animate"> (Termlink Terminal owned and operated by Nathan Schmittt) copyright(c) 2019 Termlink LLC</span>

    <p>
    </p>
    <span class="animate">[Enter Command]>>></span><span autofocus contenteditable="true" id="inputcmd"></span>
    <p><span id="output"></span></p>
</div>
<div class="scanlines"></div>
```

This is where I am verifying the username and password

```
//su verification
 if (cmd == "su") {
    return "Enter [SSID:YourSSID] to login.
 }
 if (cmd == "SSID:****") {
   return "Enter [PSWD:YourPSWD] to login."
 }
 if (cmd == "pswd:********") {
   return "Password Correct, Authorized as admin"
 }
```

This is the code for handling the unknown commands

```
    //unknown commands
      return 'your command: [ ${cmd} ] is an unknown command or login id. Some commands need a slash to function, Try[ ${cmd} /] If this is an admin command try [su /${cmd} ] If this fails type '--help' or '--list' for a list of commands or type debug.exe to help us resolve this server issue'
}
```

This is the code for opening the mobile keyboard

```
//open iOS keyboard
    function openKeyboard(){
      input.focus();
    }
```

> This is what my terminal looks like...
>   [My Terminal Live View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lZtj.png)
>
> please note the text is being printed through the html and is being styled through css

Comment: Do you have a backend? The only way you can do password protection wihtout a DB or backend authentication would be to hard code the password which would take 2 seconds to look through the src code and find.

Comment: No, I do not have a backend. How would I get a backend or hard code the password? This runs off of codepen.io. Here is the link https://codepen.io/UserIsOffline/pen/moqbzm

Comment: It depends on how secure/serious this "fake" terminal is meant to be. Running any kind of password validation on the front end (i.e without a back end) is not going to be very secure because anything running on the front end is viewable by the user. Otherwise, you're going to want to look into some back end technologies (e.g. php, sql, asp.net...) to store and validate passwords.

Comment: It's just to show my students how returns work, not very important. I want to put a password on it so it looks real.

Comment: The next lesson is backend, I already have that covered

Comment: That lesson does not use a terminal. I already promised them I would show them a "fake" terminal

Comment: If security is of no concern then to hardcode the passwd you would simply check wherever you handle the input of the password. if( passwordInputVar === 'myhardcodedpassword') { //user logged in }